# How does CursorLoader with LoaderManager know to send the cursor to a CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-loadermanager, android-cursorloader

I was going through some of my code and I realized I don't actually know how a `CursorLoader` and `LoaderManager` combination used with a `CursorAdapter` connect. Heres the part that I am confused in.

```
agendaAdapter = new MyAgendaAdapter(this, null);

makeProviderBundle(new String[] {"_id", "event_name", "start_date", "start_time",
    "end_date", "end_time", "location"}, "date(?) >= start_date and date(?) <= end_date", 
new String[]{getChosenDate(), getChosenDate()}, null);

getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, myBundle, MainDisplayActivity.this);
list.setAdapter(agendaAdapter);
```

So how does the `query()` method from my custom `ContentProvider` know to send it to that specific `CursorAdapter`? I just don't see the connection. I understand everything else in that but what this question is on. Oh and I should mention, the code works fine.

Comment: I am beginning to suspect that you are asking these questions just to screw with me, knowing that I can't help but answer (even when I am at work lol)

Comment: idk what you are talking about :) but if you're there...

Answer (score 84, accepted):

#### First of all, check out the code sample at [this post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/content-resolvers-and-content-providers.html) and [this post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) for an even more in-depth look into how the process works.

And now, to answer your questions...

> How does the query() method from my custom `ContentProvider`...?

Well, first remember that `getContentResolver().query()` doesn't invoke the content provider's `query` method directly. You are invoking the content resolver's query method, which parses the `Uri`, determines the provider you wish to invoke, and *then* calls your provider's `query` method[.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alexjlockwood.twentyfortyeight)

> How does the query get sent to that specific `CursorAdapter`?

I'll walk you through the process using the [**API Demos**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) as an example. Note that the API demos uses a `ListFragment` instead of a `ListActivity` (the difference is not important in the context of this question).

---

1. **First, create (and set up) the `CursorAdapter`**.

   ```
   mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
           getActivity(),
           android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
           null,
           new String[] { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS },
           new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 }, 
           0);
   ```

   After this statement is executed, the `SimpleCursorAdapter` knows how it should associate the cursor data with your views. Whatever data is in the cursor's `Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME` column will be associated with the view with id `android.R.id.text1`, etc.

   Note that you have passed a `null` cursor as the third argument to the constructor. This is *very important*, as we have not queried any data yet (this is the `LoaderManager` and `CursorLoader`'s job).
2. **Next, initialize the loader.**

   ```
   getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
   ```

   This tells the `LoaderManager` to create and start the `Loader` corresponding to id `0`.
3. **The `LoaderManager` calls `onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args)`.**

   `onCreateloader` returns a subclass of the `Loader<Cursor>` interface (i.e. a `CursorLoader`, in this case). This `CursorLoader` will perform the initial query and will update itself when the data changes.

   If your activity/fragment has more than one loader, then you'd use `switch(id)` to determine the specific loader that has been instructed to begin the loading process.
4. **The queried cursor is passed to `onLoadFinished()`.**

   Immediately after the `CursorLoader` is instantiated and returned in step 3, the `CursorLoader` performs the initial query on a separate thread and a cursor is returned. When the `CursorLoader` finishes the query, it returns the newly queried cursor to the `LoaderManager`, which then passes the cursor to the `onLoadFinished` method. From the documentation, "the `onLoadFinished` method is called when a previously created loader has finished its load."
5. **The queried data is associated with the `CursorAdapter`**.

   ```
   mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
   ```

   Note that `onLoadFinished` is also typically where you update the activity/fragment's UI with the queried data. This isn't necessary in this case, as we have previously called `setListAdapter(mAdapter)`. The `ListFragment` knows how to use the `CursorAdapter` (see step 1)... all we need to do is pass the adapter the cursor with `swapCursor`, and the `ListFragment` will take care of displaying the data on the screen for us.

Let me know if you have any questions (or if there are any typos, etc.).

---

### TL;DR

The cursor that contains your queried data is associated with the `CursorAdapter` in `onLoadFinished`. This is typically done by calling `mAdapter.swapCursor(data)`.

Comment: Fantastic run through on loaders

Comment: Don't thank me... thank all of the crappy, poorly-developed apps on the Android market. They are the reason why I feel responsible for explaining this process in **excessive** detail. :)

Comment: Hey @AlexLockwood quick question. If I am using a CursorLoader with a LoaderManager I do not need to worry about closing the database or cursors right. But what about when I just use it directly like `getContentResolver().query()`. In that case do I have to explicitly close them, or does all that still get handled by the class itself?

Comment: If you're using a `CursorLoader` + `LoaderManager` then you should **not** close the `Cursor`s (or else an exception will probably be thrown). The extremely short but detailed explanation of what happens is that the `Activity` tells the `LoaderManager` to perform certain actions during the `Activity` lifecycle (i.e. it will instruct the `LoaderManager` to retain its `Loader`s on a configuration change). The `LoaderManager` will react to these requests by calling the `CursorLoader` methods (i.e. `onStartLoading`, `onStopLoading`, and a bunch of other methods inherited from the `Loader` class).

Comment: Then, in these methods the `CursorLoader` will close its cursors accordingly (i.e. in [**`onReset`**](http://bit.ly/M3eFqJ), etc.). In other words, it's not the `LoaderManager` closing the cursors... it's the `LoaderManager` telling the `CursorLoader` to close the cursors.

Comment: But yeah... basically you never have to close the cursors when you are using `CursorLoader`s haha. You should close cursors queried with `getContentResolver().query` though, since raw cursors are not managed.

Comment: Where in the Activity/Fragment lifecycle is it best to call getLoaderManager().initLoader?  I have looked at Google's sourcecode, and they do it all over the place: some in onCreate, onResume, onActivityCreated, onCreateView

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I remember discussing this with some other Android devs [here](https://twitter.com/cyrilmottier/status/372646529255092224). I always initialize loaders in `onActivityCreated()`. I agree with you that Google's documentation is a little vague about this point... but I have never had any issues with initializing Loaders in `onActivityCreated()`.

Comment: I wanna have more control over my view. How can i replace `SimpleCursorAdapter` with `CursorAdapter` using `CursorLoader`?

Comment: I would like to make something clear for me (and everyone else). After I swap the cursor with oldCursor = cursorAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor), should I close the oldCursor by myself or will that be taken care of or is that even a bad idea? I know that newCursor should not be closed under no circumstances at least unitil it is not swapped for a new one.