# How to make Gridview with two TextViews?

Tags: java, android, gridview

can you help me make simple Gridview with 2 Textviews, Item is Textview 1, and SubItem is TextView 2..like this:

```
ITEM 1            ITEM 2

subitem1          subitem2
```

I have examples with ImageViews but how to accomplish this with two textviews, is there example? Should I use custom adapter or there is simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

You can place any content in the Grid item. Just you need to change the list item layout according to your requirements.You can find the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429829/how-to-add-a-textview-to-a-gridview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `ImageView` with `TextView` in your `GridView` item layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this: [How to create customized grid view with two textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303064/how-to-create-customized-grid-view-with-two-textview)

Instead of this line: `String header = first_String_Variable+"\n"+second_String_Variable;`

use this: `String header=first_String_Variable+"        "+second_String_Variable;`

and set grid by using Adapter..

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, header);
gridHeader.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Finally you have only one textview that looks like two textviews.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two `TextView` in the item of `GridView` in the custom adapter.